# Findind the determinant of the square matrix $(a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $a_{ij} = (1 - \delta_{ij}) + x_iy_j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am having difficulty finding the determinant of the following matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1y_1&1+x_1y_2&\ldots&1+x_1y_n\\
1+x_2y_1&x_2y_2&\ldots&1+x_2y_n\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1+x_ny_1&1+x_ny_2&\ldots&x_ny_n\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I considered a related matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1+x_1y_1&1+x_1y_2&...&1+x_1y_n\\
1+x_2y_1&1+x_2y_2&...&1+x_2y_n\\
...&...&...&...\\
1+x_ny_1&1+x_ny_2&...&1+x_ny_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and I was able to show that the determinant of this matrix is $0$ if $n$ is at least $3$. Then I tried to see how this can be applied to find the determinant of the first matrix, but I haven't found any connection.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
{\rm A} := 
    \begin{bmatrix}
            x_1 y_1 & 1 + x_1 y_2 & \ldots & 1 + x_1 y_n \\
        1 + x_2 y_1 &     x_2 y_2 & \ldots & 1 + x_2 y_n \\
             \vdots &      \vdots & \ddots &     \vdots \\
        1 + x_n y_1 & 1 + x_n y_2 & \ldots &     x_n y_n
    \end{bmatrix}
    = \unicode{x1D7D9}_n \unicode{x1D7D9}_n^\top - {\rm I}_n + {\rm x} {\rm y}^\top
    = (- {\rm I}_n) +
    \begin{bmatrix}
        | & | \\
        {\rm x} & \unicode{x1D7D9}_n\\ | & |
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
           |    &  | \\
        {\rm y} & \unicode{x1D7D9}_n \\ 
           |    &  |
    \end{bmatrix}^\top
$$

Using the (generalized) [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma),

$$
\det ({\rm A}) = \cdots = \color{blue}{(-1)^n \cdot \big( (1-n) ( 1 - {\rm x}^\top {\rm y} ) - ( \unicode{x1D7D9}_n^\top {\rm x} ) ( \unicode{x1D7D9}_n^\top {\rm y} ) \big)}$$

Comment: Sorry, William. My writing style may be utterly horrendous, but it is consistent with 100s of other answers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation for transpose, but I'll bow down to authority on that one. You could've reverted just that, though. The spacing made your text clearer for whomever may edit it later and the array fixed the lonely $(-I_n)$.

Comment: The color was just a matter of preference. I haven't seen it used anywhere on this site. And the blackboard $1$s look no different to me, I thought it made the text less cluttered. Aside from the notation I believe my edit improved the answer. Are we really aiming for consistency over quality?

Comment: @WilliamA.Noble I do not like $A^T$ because $T$ could be a real. And it often is in, say, optimal control.

Comment: after improving the edit only did I notice your conversation. My apologies if you did not want to approve the edit; feel free to revert. @WilliamA.Noble please do **not** edit out `\Bbb` from answers that are not your own, it appears fine on many  devices. If you must edit it, you can e.g. put `\unicode{x1D7D9}` in its place. [relevant math.meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33302/double-struck-1-in-mathjax/33303#33303)

Comment: @CalvinKhor I had no idea there was a difference, it appears the same to me on all devices I use. Thanks for the heads up, I'll refrain from doing it.

Answer (score 4):

This matrix is $\textbf{x}\textbf{y}^\textsf{T}+\textbf{1}\textbf{1}^\textsf{T}-\text{Id}$.

[Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)

$$\left(A + uv^\textsf{T}\right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - {A^{-1}uv^\textsf{T}A^{-1} \over 1 + v^\textsf{T}A^{-1}u}$$

gives when $A=-\text{Id}$

$$(-\text{Id}+\textbf{x}\textbf{y}^\textsf{T})^{-1}=-\text{Id}-{\textbf{x}\textbf{y}^\textsf{T}\over 1 - \textbf{y}^\textsf{T}\textbf{x}}$$

Now [since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)
\begin{equation}
\det(A + \mathbf{c}\mathbf{d}^T) = \det(A)(1 + \mathbf{d}^T A^{-1}\mathbf{c}) 
\end{equation}

we get for $A=-\text{Id}+\textbf{x}\textbf{y}^T$, firstly

$$\det A= \det(-\text{Id})(1-\textbf{y}^T\textbf{x})$$
Then
$$\det (A+\textbf{1}\textbf{1})=\det(A)(1+\textbf{1}^\textsf{T} (-\text{Id}-{\textbf{x}\textbf{y}^T\over 1 - \textbf{y}^\textsf{T}\textbf{x}})\textbf{1})=$$
$$=(-1)^{n+1}(1-\textbf{y}^T\textbf{x})(n-1+\frac{(\textbf{1}^\textsf{T}\textbf{x}\textbf{y}^T\textbf{1})}{1-\textbf{y}^T\textbf{x}})=(-1)^{n+1}((n-1)(1-\textbf{y}^T\textbf{x})+\textbf{1}^\textsf{T}\textbf{x}\textbf{1}^\textsf{T}\textbf{y}) $$

Comment: How do you know all of these formulas you mentioned? Are there any books that talk about these?

Comment: Well, honestly I just know that inverse/determinant of a low-rank perturbation of a matrix can be computed, and roughly what the formulas look like. Pretty much any book on matrix algebra (or "matrix analysis") will have these formulas (say, Horn-Johnson).